# Oracle SQL only: Case statement or exists query to show results based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle, case-statement

I am trying to create computed column based on some conditions by using case statement. I am so close to goal but unable to see where the query is going wrong. Hope I get some best/easier methods and some help here.

Below are the tables:
**PERSON Table:**

```
+----+--------+
| ID | PERSON |
+----+--------+
|  1 | John   |
|  2 | Scott  |
|  3 | Ruth   |
|  4 | Smith  |
|  5 | Frank  |
|  6 | Martin |
|  7 | Blake  |
+----+--------+
```

**ROLE Table:**

```
+----+------+
| ID | ROLE |
+----+------+
|  1 | JJJ  |
|  2 | Auth |
|  3 | AAA  |
|  4 | MMM  |
|  5 | KKK  |
|  6 | BBB  |
+----+------+
```

and last one is the detail table
**PERSON_ROLE Table:**

```
+----+-----------+---------+
| ID | PERSON_ID | ROLE_ID |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  1 |         1 |       1 |
|  2 |         2 |       2 |
|  3 |         2 |       3 |
|  4 |         2 |       4 |
|  5 |         3 |       1 |
|  6 |         3 |       5 |
|  7 |         4 |       3 |
|  8 |         5 |       6 |
|  9 |         6 |       3 |
| 10 |         6 |       6 |
| 11 |         6 |       2 |
| 12 |         7 |       5 |
| 13 |         7 |       6 |
+----+-----------+---------+
```

**Desired/Expected output:**

```
+--------+--------+----------+
| PERSON | MYROLE | MYACCESS |
+--------+--------+----------+
| John   | JJJ    |          |
| Scott  | Auth   | Remove   |
| Scott  | AAA    |          |
| Scott  | MMM    |          |
| Ruth   | JJJ    |          |
| Ruth   | KKK    |          |
| Smith  | AAA    | Add      |
| Frank  | BBB    | Add      |
| Martin | AAA    |          |
| Martin | BBB    |          |
| Martin | Auth   | Remove   |
| Blake  | KKK    |          |
| Blake  | BBB    | Add      |
+--------+--------+----------+
```

Below are the conditions:

1. If **Person** has **Role** "AAA" or "BBB" and not "Auth" then **MYAccess** column should show value as "Add" for that Person. All other values should be null.
2. If **Person** has **Role** "Auth" then **MYAccess** column should show "Remove" only for that row. Even if same Person has "AAA" or "BBB" or any other value it should show null.

**Below is the actual output I am getting which is partially correct:**

```
+--------+--------+----------+
| PERSON | MYROLE | MYACCESS |
+--------+--------+----------+
| Blake  | KKK    |          |
| Blake  | BBB    | Add      |
| Frank  | BBB    | Add      |
| John   | JJJ    |          |
| Martin | AUTH   | Remove   |
| Martin | BBB    | Add      |
| Martin | AAA    | Add      |
| Ruth   | JJJ    |          |
| Ruth   | KKK    |          |
| Scott  | AAA    | Add      |
| Scott  | AUTH   | Remove   |
| Scott  | MMM    |          |
| Smith  | AAA    | Add      |
+--------+--------+----------+
```

For Persons Martin and Scott, it should show only "Remove" but I am getting "Add" as well.

Below is the query:

```
SELECT p.person,upper(r.role) myrole,
case when p.person in (select p.person from  person ut where ut.person = p.person and upper(r.role) = upper('Auth')) then 'Remove' 
     when p.person in (select p.person from  person ut where ut.person = p.person and (upper(r.role) = upper('Auth') or (upper(r.role) = upper('AAA') or upper(r.role) = upper('BBB')))) then 'Add' else null
end as myaccess
FROM person p
       join person_role pr
         ON p.id = pr.person_id
       join myrole r
         ON r.id = pr.role_id
order by p.person
```

**DDL Script:**

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    person  VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
);

INSERT INTO person (
    id,
    person
) VALUES (
    1,
    'John'
);

INSERT INTO person (
    id,
    person
) VALUES (
    2,
    'Scott'
);

INSERT INTO person (
    id,
    person
) VALUES (
    3,
    'Ruth'
);

INSERT INTO person (
    id,
    person
) VALUES (
    4,
    'Smith'
);

INSERT INTO person (
    id,
    person
) VALUES (
    5,
    'Frank'
);

INSERT INTO person (
    id,
    person
) VALUES (
    6,
    'Martin'
);

INSERT INTO person (
    id,
    person
) VALUES (
    7,
    'Blake'
);

ALTER TABLE person ADD CONSTRAINT person_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id );


CREATE TABLE myrole (
    id    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    role  VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
);

INSERT INTO myrole (
    id,
    role
) VALUES (
    1,
    'JJJ'
);

INSERT INTO myrole (
    id,
    role
) VALUES (
    2,
    'Auth'
);

INSERT INTO myrole (
    id,
    role
) VALUES (
    3,
    'AAA'
);

INSERT INTO myrole (
    id,
    role
) VALUES (
    4,
    'MMM'
);

INSERT INTO myrole (
    id,
    role
) VALUES (
    5,
    'KKK'
);

INSERT INTO myrole (
    id,
    role
) VALUES (
    6,
    'BBB'
);

ALTER TABLE myrole ADD CONSTRAINT myrole_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id );


CREATE TABLE person_role (
    id         INTEGER NOT NULL,
    person_id  INTEGER,
    myrole_id  INTEGER
);

ALTER TABLE person_role ADD CONSTRAINT person_role_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id );

CREATE SEQUENCE myrole_seq START WITH 1 NOCACHE;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER myrole_tr BEFORE
    INSERT ON myrole
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN ( new.id IS NULL )
BEGIN
    :new.id := myrole_seq.nextval;
END;
/

CREATE SEQUENCE person_seq START WITH 1 NOCACHE;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER person_tr BEFORE
    INSERT ON person
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN ( new.id IS NULL )
BEGIN
    :new.id := person_seq.nextval;
END;
/

CREATE SEQUENCE person_role_seq START WITH 1 NOCACHE;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER person_role_tr BEFORE
    INSERT ON person_role
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN ( new.id IS NULL )
BEGIN
    :new.id := person_role_seq.nextval;
END;
/
```

Thanks
Richa

Comment: Looks like a data issue or your OR statement for the ADD section needs some work.  I see both Scott and Martin in your table twice.  First one matches with Remove column, and with your OR statement logic looks like it is making the 2nd row for those 2 records as ADD.  Try breaking out your case statement into sections and run individually to test to narrow it down.

Comment: Also if you can post a repeatable code so we can copy/paste it to run it will help you get assistance faster and easier https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: "join" is not a type of table. What you call the "join" table is known as a "detail" table. I'll edit your post to make the change, I wanted to let you know what I am doing and why.

Comment: Also, are you sure your detail table is the correct one? In the query it seems to only have the id's (as it should), not the names and the role names. Your "detail" table - as posted now - already has the names and the role names, there would be no need to join to the detail tables.

Comment: @mathguy thank you for the change. Detail table has only ID's. I showed desired output table as an example how my output should look and the query I wrote does that except its not computing correctly

Comment: @Brad I am generating DDL. Will post it in a while. Thank you

Comment: Added DDL script with data as @Brad suggested. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you're looking for ?
In your conditions you're saying:
*"If Person has Role "AAA" or "BBB" and not "Auth" then MYAccess column should show value as "Add" for that Person. All other values should be null.
"*
Scott has Auth so this condition yields false. According to this rule Scott should not have "Add". In your expected output it has "Add". Am I missing something ?

```
WITH person_roles (id, person_id, role_id) AS
(
SELECT  1, 1,1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 2,2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 2,3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 2,4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 3,1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6, 3,5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7, 4,3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 5,6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9, 6,3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 6,6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 6,2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 7,5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13, 7,6 FROM DUAL
),persons (id, person) AS
(
SELECT   1,'John' FROM DUAL UNION ALL   
SELECT   2,'Scott' FROM DUAL UNION ALL  
SELECT   3,'Ruth' FROM DUAL UNION ALL   
SELECT   4,'Smith' FROM DUAL UNION ALL  
SELECT   5,'Frank' FROM DUAL UNION ALL  
SELECT   6,'Martin' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT   7,'Blake' FROM DUAL
),roles (id, role) AS
(
SELECT 1,'JJJ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL   
SELECT 2,'Auth' FROM DUAL UNION ALL  
SELECT 3,'AAA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL   
SELECT 4,'MMM' FROM DUAL UNION ALL   
SELECT 5,'KKK' FROM DUAL UNION ALL   
SELECT 6,'BBB' FROM DUAL 
), rule_1(person_id, role_type)  AS
(
SELECT p.id, MIN(CASE WHEN r.ROLE = 'Auth' THEN 0 WHEN r.ROLE in ('AAA','BBB') THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) 
  FROM person_roles pr 
  JOIN persons p ON p.id = pr.person_id 
  JOIN roles r ON r.id = pr.role_id
  GROUP BY p.id
)
SELECT p.person, r.role, 
  CASE 
    WHEN rl.role_type = 1 AND r.role IN ('AAA','BBB') THEN 'Add'  
    WHEN rl.role_type = 0 AND r.role = 'Auth' THEN 'Remove' 
  END as action
  FROM person_roles pr 
  JOIN persons p ON p.id = pr.person_id 
  JOIN roles r ON r.id = pr.role_id
  JOIN rule_1 rl ON rl.person_id = pr.person_id
ORDER BY p.person

PERSON ROLE ACTION
------ ---- ------
Blake  BBB  Add   
Blake  KKK        
Frank  BBB  Add   
John   JJJ        
Martin AAA        
Martin Auth Remove
Martin BBB        
Ruth   KKK        
Ruth   JJJ        
Scott  MMM        
Scott  AAA        
Scott  Auth Remove
Smith  AAA  Add
```

If you want to avoid the CTE (with clause) you can replace the last 2 statements with 1:

```
SELECT p.person, r.role, 
  CASE 
    WHEN rl.role_type = 1 AND r.role IN ('AAA','BBB') THEN 'Add'  
    WHEN rl.role_type = 0 AND r.role = 'Auth' THEN 'Remove' 
  END as action
  FROM person_roles pr 
  JOIN persons p ON p.id = pr.person_id 
  JOIN roles r ON r.id = pr.role_id
  JOIN (
    SELECT p.id, MIN(CASE WHEN r.ROLE = 'Auth' THEN 0 WHEN r.ROLE in ('AAA','BBB') THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) as role_type
    FROM person_roles pr 
    JOIN persons p ON p.id = pr.person_id 
    JOIN roles r ON r.id = pr.role_id
    GROUP BY p.id
    ) rl ON rl.id = pr.person_id
ORDER BY p.person
```

Comment: Koen Lostrie your understanding is correct. Thank you for the query. May I know if same output can be generated by using only one select statement instead of "WITH" clause? I ask since I have other columns to show in my real-time query.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you Koen Lostrie. I have accepted your answer and upvoted. Thank you for your time and help

Comment: Happy to help. --Koen

Comment: How to do listagg on another column? I tried to add table structure here but stackoverflow has only text area. So created another post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67536862/oracle-sql-listagg-remove-duplicates-with-case-statement-conditions